# Spark sql - Pyspark string to date conversion

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've a column with the data `20180501` in string format, I want to convert it to date format, tried using

```
to_date(cast(unix_timestamp('20180501', 'YYYYMMDD') as timestamp))'
```

but still it didn't worked. I'm using Spark SQL with dataframes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format should be `yyyyMMdd`:

```py
spark.sql("SELECT to_date(cast(unix_timestamp('20180501', 'yyyyMMdd') as timestamp))").show()
# +------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |to_date(CAST(unix_timestamp('20180501', 'yyyyMMdd') AS TIMESTAMP))|
# +------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |                                                        2018-05-01|
# +------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the other answer the format you use is incorrect. But you can also use `to_date` directly:

```
spark.sql("SELECT to_date('20180501', 'yyyyMMdd')").show()
+-------------------------------+
|to_date('20180501', 'yyyyMMdd')|
+-------------------------------+
|                     2018-05-01|
+-------------------------------+
```